# Facebook privacy setting

Tags: facebook

Is it possible for Facebook user to restrict their photo from certain people to be seen? Even though they are not friend on Facebook. It was weird because these photos were public posted and everyone can see it. All these people are not on the friend list either. But only my account I couldn't see it.
If that option is available. How can I do that?

I thought we could only restricted the audience when they are on our friend list.

Answer (score 0):

If the photo is public then everyone can see it (logged in or not). There is no specific privacy setting to limit this.

Possible guesses for you not seeing the photo

- You are blocked from the owner
- A Facebook bug
- A Page restriction (if the owner is a page and has country/alcohol settings imposed)